# Rapidminer 7.0 how can i run a loop without showing result each iteration?

Tags: rapidminer

I'm new to rapidminer. How can I run a loop without showing result each iteration? When I use "loop" or "loop until" operator,I need to push the button,"run processes locally" ,100 times to get the final meaningful result.
Is it possible one button 100 iterations?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<process version="7.0.001">
<context>
<input/>
<output/>
<macros/>
</context>
<operator activated="true" class="process" compatibility="7.0.001" expanded="true" name="Process">
<process expanded="true">
  <operator activated="true" class="retrieve" compatibility="7.0.001" expanded="true" height="68" name="Retrieve traffic2014week" width="90" x="45" y="34">
    <parameter key="repository_entry" value="//My First Prediction/Data/traffic2014week"/>
  </operator>
  <operator activated="true" class="retrieve" compatibility="7.0.001" expanded="true" height="68" name="Retrieve traffic2015week" width="90" x="45" y="238">
    <parameter key="repository_entry" value="//My First Prediction/Data/traffic2015week"/>
  </operator>
  <operator activated="true" class="append" compatibility="7.0.001" expanded="true" height="103" name="Append" width="90" x="112" y="85"/>
  <operator activated="true" class="select_attributes" compatibility="7.0.001" expanded="true" height="82" name="Select Attributes" width="90" x="246" y="85">
    <parameter key="attribute_filter_type" value="single"/>
    <parameter key="attribute" value="sum"/>
  </operator>
  <operator activated="true" class="series:windowing" compatibility="5.3.000" expanded="true" height="82" name="Windowing" width="90" x="380" y="85">
    <parameter key="window_size" value="288"/>
    <parameter key="step_size" value="288"/>
  </operator>
  <operator activated="true" class="loop" compatibility="7.0.001" expanded="true" height="82" name="Loop" width="90" x="514" y="85">
    <parameter key="set_iteration_macro" value="true"/>
    <parameter key="macro_start_value" value="345"/>
    <parameter key="iterations" value="2"/>
    <process expanded="true">
      <operator activated="true" class="filter_example_range" compatibility="7.0.001" expanded="true" height="82" name="Filter Example Range" width="90" x="45" y="34">
        <parameter key="first_example" value="1"/>
        <parameter key="last_example" value="%{iteration}"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="k_means" compatibility="7.0.001" expanded="true" height="82" name="Clustering" width="90" x="179" y="34">
        <parameter key="k" value="7"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="extract_macro" compatibility="7.0.001" expanded="true" height="68" name="Extract Macro" width="90" x="313" y="34">
        <parameter key="macro" value="x"/>
        <parameter key="macro_type" value="data_value"/>
        <parameter key="attribute_name" value="cluster"/>
        <parameter key="example_index" value="%{iteration}"/>
        <list key="additional_macros"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" breakpoints="after" class="filter_examples" compatibility="6.4.000" expanded="true" height="103" name="ExampleFilter" width="90" x="447" y="34">
        <parameter key="parameter_string" value="cluster = %{x}"/>
        <parameter key="condition_class" value="attribute_value_filter"/>
        <list key="filters_list"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="aggregate" compatibility="7.0.001" expanded="true" height="82" name="Aggregate" width="90" x="581" y="34">
        <parameter key="use_default_aggregation" value="true"/>
        <list key="aggregation_attributes"/>
      </operator>
      <connect from_port="input 1" to_op="Filter Example Range" to_port="example set input"/>
      <connect from_op="Filter Example Range" from_port="example set output" to_op="Clustering" to_port="example set"/>
      <connect from_op="Clustering" from_port="clustered set" to_op="Extract Macro" to_port="example set"/>
      <connect from_op="Extract Macro" from_port="example set" to_op="ExampleFilter" to_port="example set input"/>
      <connect from_op="ExampleFilter" from_port="example set output" to_op="Aggregate" to_port="example set input"/>
      <connect from_op="Aggregate" from_port="example set output" to_port="output 1"/>
      <portSpacing port="source_input 1" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="source_input 2" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_output 1" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_output 2" spacing="0"/>
    </process>
  </operator>
  <operator activated="true" class="append" compatibility="7.0.001" expanded="true" height="82" name="Append2" width="90" x="648" y="85"/>
  <operator activated="true" class="write_csv" compatibility="7.0.001" expanded="true" height="82" name="Write CSV" width="90" x="782" y="85">
    <parameter key="csv_file" value="D:\7111.csv"/>
  </operator>
  <connect from_op="Retrieve traffic2014week" from_port="output" to_op="Append" to_port="example set 1"/>
  <connect from_op="Retrieve traffic2015week" from_port="output" to_op="Append" to_port="example set 2"/>
  <connect from_op="Append" from_port="merged set" to_op="Select Attributes" to_port="example set input"/>
  <connect from_op="Select Attributes" from_port="example set output" to_op="Windowing" to_port="example set input"/>
  <connect from_op="Windowing" from_port="example set output" to_op="Loop" to_port="input 1"/>
  <connect from_op="Loop" from_port="output 1" to_op="Append2" to_port="example set 1"/>
  <connect from_op="Append2" from_port="merged set" to_op="Write CSV" to_port="input"/>
  <connect from_op="Write CSV" from_port="through" to_port="result 1"/>
  <portSpacing port="source_input 1" spacing="0"/>
  <portSpacing port="sink_result 1" spacing="0"/>
  <portSpacing port="sink_result 2" spacing="0"/>
</process>
</operator>
</process>
```

Comment: You should probably show the code your tried (that shows results) so that others can help you to *modify* it

Comment: Yes, without a demo process it is hard to see the problem.  Under _View -> Show Panel -> XML_ you can open the XML description of our process, that can be easily shared.    Otherwise it sounds like you have a break point somewhere in your loop.

Comment: Sorry for my carelessness. Thank you for your advises.

Answer (score 0):

I find the mistake that I forget to uncheck the option "Breakpoint after" in one operator in the loop. 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2JuUw4KSF39T2syUVpVMlFGNlk